# MS Bot greets twice after added in webchat

Tags: c#, azure, web, frameworks, bots

I have the following scenario: A bot is provided via webchat in a webpage. When the webpage is loaded, the bot greets and immediately displays some options a user can pick from. Here is the code, used in MessagesController:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message || activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate &&
               !activity.MembersAdded.Any(r => r.Name == "Bot"))
                return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
            new RootDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

and part from the RootDialog class:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{        
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var message = context.MakeMessage();
        var attachment = GetHeroCard();
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        await context.PostAsync(message);
        context.Wait(this.ShowFirstCategoryRefinement);
    }
    public virtual async Task ShowFirstCategoryRefinement(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        var message = await activity;
        IEnumerable<string> options = this.mainCategories;

        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context,
            resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
            options: options,
            prompt: "Please select product category:",
            retry: "Selected category not available. Please try again.",
            promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
            );
    }
...
}
```

What actually happens is: user opens the page, the bot greets and shows some options. When the user picks an option, the bot greets again and shows the same options. If the user again picks an option the dialog continues normally.

How shall this be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Try debugging step by step

Comment: Interesting, my experience of webchat (using the iFrame) is there is no conversation update until the user sends a message, though we would like it to happen... Anyway, could this be related to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/98 ?

Comment: They use different method. And @MarkBenovsky debugging step by step does not help, because this code works as expected when tested with the bot emulator. This happens only after deploying in Azure and using webchat with direct line.